# Implementing flutter_parsed_text and readmore in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-text

How can I implement [flutter_parsed_text](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_parsed_text) with [ReadMore](https:///pub.dev/packages/readmore) in flutter?

Comment: can I ask you what is your purpose to combine this two?

Comment: Yeah, because I'am having my own set matches that i can acheive using flutter_parsed_text and also i want to implement readmore option if the provided text exceeds the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced similar issue like you. So I created my own package [parsed_readmore](https://pub.dev/packages/parsed_readmore). It is like readmore on steroids.
What it is capable of:

- Implementing all the features that readmore has.
- Automatically parses the urls present in the text into hyperlinks which launches the browser on click event.
- All the text components including the parsed urls, delimiter, clickable texts, etc can be given separate custom styles.
- Addition of user defined action on clicking the hyperlinks.
- Option to add custom text styles for targeted text (for eg: defining a different text style for all the occurence of the word "apple" in the text).

Please do give it a try and let me know if I should do some modifications in it.